# What is my chance to find a block on a TestNet ?

Tags: testnet

My gethashespersec is 4806082,  on the TestNet what is my real chance to find a block ?

Comment: To answer this question I think we need to find the total hash rate of the Testnet network. I'm not sure where this information could be found.

Comment: Unlike the main network, it's not so easy to estimate the total Testnet hash rate from the difficulty and block times, because of the "difficulty drops to 1 after 20 minutes" rule.  I've been thinking about this question and I'll try to post something in the next couple days if I have time.  Of course, the hash rate of Testnet also can be expected to fluctuate much more than the main network, as people bring miners online and offline for testing.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a chart of testnet hashrate in time...

Answer (score 3):

You have almost 5MH/s, so at the [current difficulty](http://blockexplorer.com/testnet/q/getdifficulty) = 1787.78664453 and given, that base diff for testnet is 0.5 diff for main btc network, you can put this into [calculator](http://blockchained.com/profit/index.php), and you get

> 9 days, 6 hours

. Hope this solves your case.